# How to change label text of a form, which is opened in different thread?

Tags: c++, winforms, multithreading, visual-c++, c++-cli

I've started a form in new thread, because of some GUI lagging (form become non responsive) problems. This thread starts when a function (some_function()) is called. Such as...

```
/*========some_function=========*/
     void some_function()
     {
          System::Threading::Thread^ t1;
          System::Threading::ThreadStart^ ts = gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(&ThreadProc);
          t1 = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(ts);
          t1->Start();
          while(condition)
          {
               Form1^ f1=gcnew Form1();
              //some coding
              //to change the values of a different form (Form1)
          }
     }

/*======ThreadProc=========*/
    void ThreadProc()
    {
         Form1^ f1=gcnew Form1();
         f1->Show(); //OR Application::Run(Form1());
    }
```

Now the problem is about changing values of the form (Form1), such as label text, progress bar etc., within the "while" loop. Is tehre any way to change values of form, which is open in different thread ?

Comment: This will **not** solve any problems, just add a *lot* of new ones.  Identify the cause of the 'lagging' first.

Comment: @HansPassant :: Lagging is because of the function contains several loops. I used form->show(); and then the loops updates different progress bars and labels of the form.
And the form becomes non-responsive.
Is there any better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Control::Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30s4t80c.aspx) to throw a method into a safe thread to change a control. To show the form of your example:

```
public delegate void SwapControlVisibleDelegate(Control^ target);

public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
  /*Ctor and InitializeComponents for Form1*/
  /*...*/

  protected : 
    virtual void OnShown(EventArgs^ e) override
    {
        __super::OnShown(e);
        some_function();
    }


    void some_function()
    {
        System::Threading::Thread^ t1;
        System::Threading::ThreadStart^ ts = gcnew ystem::Threading::ThreadStart(this, &Form1::ThreadProc);
        t1 = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(ts);
        t1->Start();

    }

    void ThreadProc()
    {
        Threading::Thread::Sleep(2000);
        for each(Control^ c in this->Controls)
        {
            SwapVisible(c);
        }
    }


    void SwapVisible(Control^ c)
    {
        if(c->InvokeRequired) // If this is not a safe thread...
        {
            c->Invoke(gcnew SwapControlVisibleDelegate(this, &Form1::SwapVisible), (Object^)c);
        }else{
            c->Visible ^= true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how to call a method control into the a safe thread for doing changes.
Right now I have read your comment for the question. Take a look on [BackgroundWorker component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), it is perfect to run asynchronous task with cancellation support and also it implements events to receive notifications about progress and end of the tasks.

Comment: error C3352: 'void Form1::InvokeShow(Form1 ^)' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (Form1 ^)'